# how to set text in button with image in center - android?

Tags: android

I have a button with inage in background and I set text for the button on the right of the image, how to set the text verticaly ??

Answer (score 0):

For XML you'll need the android:gravity property, in code it would be TextView.setGravity() you're after.

Comment: i did but nothing effect , i mean in the same button view i want the text to come in the middle of the image of the byttun >

Answer (score 0):

Android:gravity in the XML. Set it to "center"
[link text](http://www.androidpeople.com/tag/gravity/)